# passing django form values to html

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am working on a Django project and I have a form with a username field. I am trying to pass the username (just the value not the whole field that is given by form.username) from the form using form.fields['username'] but I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['username']' from 'form.fields['username']'
```

my html is:

```
{{form.fields['username']}}
```

and my form is :

```
class RegisterationForm (forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField(initial = 'eg. John',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(initial = 'eg. lennon',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(initial = 'eg. J.Lennon',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(initial = 'form: example@something.com',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(initial = '******',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(initial = '******',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
```

My form is not bounded but since it has initial value I was expecting to see the initial value in the form.fields['username'] but I still get an error. I have passed the form from the view function btw. (when I just put `{{form}}` I do get the whole form on my HTML)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it is `{{form.NAME_OF_THE_FIELD}}` so for you it should be `{{form.username}}`

Edit:

Then to access username value it should be `{{ form.username.value }}`

Comment: form.username is the whole field for the username. I am only trying to access the value inside the username. For example, I am trying to get the "eg. J.Lennon" here

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, to access the field's value it's like that {{ form.NAME_OF_THE_FIELD.value }}

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking for :) @ddalu5

Answer (score 1):

As @ddalu5 mentioned the right command for the HTML is

```
{{from.username.value}}
```

It is funny how I could not find that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`{{form.fields['username']}}` is invalid django template syntax. You should use `{{ form.name_of_field }}` instead.

Check django doc about [render form fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

You can't do dict lookup in django template using `[]`, there's only `.` lookup. Check django doc about [the sequence of dot lookup in django template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).